# Pandas groupby and compute ratio of values with NA in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like as below

```
id,status,amount,qty
1,pass,123,4500
1,pass,156,3210
1,fail,687,2137
1,fail,456,1236
2,pass,216,324
2,pass,678,241
2,nan,637,213
2,pass,213,543

df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
```

I would like to do the below

a) Groupby `id` and compute the pass percentage for each id

b) Groupby `id` and compute the average `amount` for each id

So, I tried the below

```
df['amt_avg'] = df.groupby('id')['amount'].mean()
df['pass_pct'] = df.groupby('status').apply(lambda x: x['status']/ x['status'].count())
df['fail_pct'] = df.groupby('status').apply(lambda x: x['status']/ x['status'].count())
```

but this doesn't work.

I am having trouble in getting the pass percentage.

In my real data I have lot of columns like `status` for which I have to find these % distribution of a specific value (ex: pass)

I expect my output to be like as below

```
id,pass_pct,fail_pct,amt_avg
1,50,50,2770.75
2,75,0,330.25
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with replace missing values by `nan` with remove `nan` column and then add new column `amt_avg` by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
s = df.groupby('id')['qty'].mean()

df  = (pd.crosstab(df['id'], df['status'].fillna('nan'), normalize=0)
          .drop('nan', 1)
          .mul(100)
          .join(s.rename('amt_avg')))

print (df)
    fail  pass  amt_avg
id                     
1   50.0  50.0  2770.75
2    0.0  75.0   330.25
```

Comment: Looks nice. but the output is slightly incorrect for `id=2` because the `pass` is only `75%`

Comment: We should not count `NA` under `pass_pct`

Comment: great. under the cross tab, we can put as many columns as we want?

Comment: @TheGreat - yes, it is possible.